# How can I get certain datas in a data frame when I set the start date and the end date?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

so..this is my 7th day learning python dataframe and I want to try something new.

The goal is simple. Take two dates from user[(ex) start:1999-12-21, end:2002-01-01] and make a dataframe from it.
so here is what I do so far

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import datetime

plt.rc('font', family = 'Malgun Gothic')
df = pd.read_csv('seoul.csv', encoding = 'cp949', index_col=0)
del df['지점']


while True:
        try:
            #time.sleep(1)
            the_date = input("'yyyy-mm-dd' start: ")
            a = df.index.str.contains(the_date)
            df2 = df[a]
            if df2.empty == True:
                print("That date is not existed.")
                continue
            #time.sleep(1)
            the_date2 = input("'yyyy-mm-dd'end: ")
            b = df.index.str.contains(the_date2)
            df3 = df[b]
            if df3.empty == True:
                print("That date is not existed.")
                continue
            #time.sleep(1)
        except ValueError :
            print("You input a wrong way. Try again.")
            #time.sleep(3)
            continue
```

I get 2 dates from a user and make sure to check it whether those two are actually in the data.
but I have no idea what to do next..
but It got an error. Is there anyone give me a guidance what to do next? or can anyone give some examples? Sorry my English is pretty rubbish.

Comment: You want to have the data **between** those two dates ? 
Provided you dataframe has a datetim index then you can simply do :

`data_btw_dates = df[date_1:date_2]`

Comment: Post the error you're getting. Also provide a sample of what's in the csv file (just columns and a few rows) to debug the issue.